# The requested URL was rejected.

Tags: apache, networking, web, firewall, web-application-firewall

We are getting the following issue while openging the site.
Please consult with your administrator.Your support ID is: 12573575673107663300

Can any one help us to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your network connected to corporate network, which has specific proxy settings?

Comment: yes. My network is connted to corporate network, which has specific proxy settings

Comment: Then the above error should be displayed with their network settings. This is not something related to application development, from my knowledge.

Comment: Yes. There was some issue in web application firewall (WAF) is an application firewall. It applies a set of rules to an HTTP conversation which was not suitable by my app.

Comment: @MontiChandra How did you fix this. I am facing the same issue.